# Remove newline character after pipe

Tags: pipe, newlines, base64

I want to do Base64 encode with a command

```
echo -en "my_message" | openssl sha1 -hmac "secret_key" | base64
```

The output string of `openssl` is as expected, but the output of base64 is not as the output from openssl has a new line character. If I run the command

```
echo -en "my_message" | openssl sha1 -hmac "secret_key" | xargs echo -n | base64
```

Then the final output is correct.

I wonder if there is a more elegant way for this command

Comment: `tr -d '\n'` ??

Comment: The output is correct, but I am looking for a way to remove the command after the 2nd pipe.

Comment: You don't want to add to the pipeline, but force `openssl` to not output a newline?

Comment: I suspect you actually want `printf %s "my_message" | openssl sha1 -binary -hmac "secret_key" | base64` as I don't expect you'd want to base64 the text version of openssl's output

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You are right about the Base64. But what bothers me is how to remove the newline in the next pipe, sorry for my poor question.

Comment: @DinoTw Did you try with the `-binary` option as Stéphane suggested?